# How to use :not selector in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

My question says everything. I am new in CSS. I am trying to use following code but it is not working:

```
ul.verticalNav {
    /*declaration*/
}

ul.verticalNav li {
    /*declaration*/
}

ul.verticalNav li a {
    /*declaration*/
}

ul.verticalNav li a:not(:nth-last-child(1)) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #323232;
}
```

The class `ul.verticalNav li a:not(:nth-last-child(1))` is not creating borders. The HTML is:

```
<ul class="verticalNav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">View Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Edit Profile</a></li>
    <li class="bottomLeftMenuItem"><a class="bottomLeftMenuItem" href="#">Search Profile</a></li>
</ul>
```

I am unable to find the problem.

Thanks in advance.

---

I am using Firefox 12.0 and Google Chrome 18.0.1025.168 m.

Comment: You could replace `:nth-last-child(1)` by `:last-child`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your selector is wrong, it should be

```
ul.verticalNav li:not(:nth-last-child(1)) a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #323232;
}​
```

That's because with your markup, `<a>` is always going to be the last child of its `<li>` parent. What you want is to apply the style to `<a>`s inside any `<li>` which is not a last child.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much and thanks for the explanation, it helped me to understand the sequence and relations of tags.